# How can I allow setState to be used throughout the app with context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi this may be a very noob question I apologize in advance, I'm learning react and I am using state with context. I have been able to use context and pass info between components I am now trying to add a form component that needs to tap into the input value and update the state.

is it possible to grab the set state via the context file and update it in another component?

this is the code I have for context file:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("john smith");
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={name}  >
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContextProvider;
```

**This is the form component**

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { UserContext } from './UserContext'

const Form = () => {
const  name = useContext(UserContext)
const setName = useContext(UserContext)
const submitHandler = (e) => {

return (
    e.preventDefault()
     )
  }

    return (
          <>
        {name}
        <form onSubmit = {submitHandler}>
          <input
          onChange= {(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          value = {name}
          type='text'
          placeholder = 'enter name'
          />
        </form>
        </>)
   }

export default Form;
```

I have tried adding setName on the form component:

```
const  name = useContext(UserContext)
const setName = useContext(UserContext)
```

and also on the value of props tried this as well in the context value:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{name: name, setName}}  >
```

but i get an error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, setName})

I'm not sure what to do to allow me to update the state from the form component using context.

Hope you can help?
Thanks

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Answer (score 0):

`useContext` returns what you define in the `value` prop. In your case, you are setting an Object with the `name` and `setName` properties.

You can get hold to the properties values like so:

```
const { name, setName } = useContext(UserContext);

// or

const user = useContext(UserContext);

console.log(user.name);
user.setName('John Doe');
```